# Swift enum with custom object raw value

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I try to implement a state machine for my ViewController, so i create a enum to express the possible state of my ViewController :

```
enum SMState:RawRepresentable{
    case empty,data(UIView),failed(UIView),noData(UIView)
}
```

- The 4 state of enum is suitable for my ViewController, and some state associate with a custom view to show when ViewController enter the specify state.
- Then i make SMState impl [RawRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable) Protocol

---

```
enum SMState:RawRepresentable{
        case empty,data(UIView),failed(UIView),noData(UIView)
        typealias RawValue = UIView

    init?(rawValue: SMState.RawValue) {
        // rawValue is a view but i can't judge what to return
        return what???
    }

    var rawValue: UIView{
        switch self {
        case .data(let v):
            return v
        case .failed(let v):
            return v
        case .noData(let v):
            return v
        case .empty:
            return UIView()
        }
    }
}
```

### How should i implement `init?(rawValue:SMState.RawValue)` function above, i can't image how to do this.

---

## Update

#### Why i implement `RawRepresentable` :

I think `enum` is more suitable for representable different state for `ViewController` instead of `Class or Struct`, but `enum` cannot contains `stored property`, it can only carry a `UIView` Object through `RawRepresentable`, any better idea or magic is welcome :D

Comment: Why do you need to conform to `RawRepresentable`? You're quite correct that there's no sensible way to implement the initialiser requirement – you're missing the information for what case to initialise to (unless there's some default case you want to use).

Comment: Are you aware that a *raw* value and an *associated* value are quite different things?

Comment: @vadian I am not good at English, and i think they are represent for the same thing, i have edit my question to correct it.

Comment: `case something(thisIsAnAssociatedValue)` vs. `case otherThing = "This is a String rawValue"`

Comment: No they do no represent the same thing. A raw value is a fixed relationship between case and value e.g `case empty = myView1, data = myView2` etc. An associated value is a dynamic value of the specified type. You can use associated values without adopting `RawRepresentable` and vice versa.

Comment: @Hamish Yep, you are right, i can't fulfill what the protocol `RawRepresentable` need, and i think enum is more suitable for representable different state for ViewController instead of `Class or Struct`, but enum cannot contains `stored property`, it can only carry a `UIView` Object through `RawRepresentable`, any better idea is welcome .

Comment: @vadian Gotcha, simple and clear, thanks :D

Comment: @ShawnWang Regarding your update, what do you mean by "it can only carry a `UIView` Object through  `RawRepresentable`"? It currently can carry a `UIView` instance in the associated values for most of its cases. I *think* all you want is just a computed property (much like your implementation of `rawValue`; but named something else), that returns a `UIView?`, returning `nil` in the case of `.empty`. You should drop the conformance to `RawRepresentable`.

Comment: @Hamish Great inspiration, thanks ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hamish You are right, i shouldn't insist using `RawRepresentable`, after a nice sleep, i finally archive what i want :

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

enum SMState{
    case empty,data(UIView),failed(UIView),noData(UIView)
}

extension SMState{
    init() {
        self = .empty
    }
    init(failed view:UIView) {
        self = .failed(view)
    }
    init(data view:UIView) {
        self = .data(view)
    }
    init(noData view:UIView) {
        self = .noData(view)
    }
}

let state = SMState(failed: UIView())


switch state {

case .failed(let v):
    print(v)

default:break

}
```

1. This is what i want, each `enum` state own a separate `View`, i do different operation in different state, using the `View` that the state carry ~
2. This approach is much like using `Class`, in my situation, i am not sure that there may be more states, then it is impossible to extend or subclass the `SMState` because its a `enum`, i am think about using `Class`
3. What i am trying to do is much like this library [StatefulViewController](https://github.com/aschuch/StatefulViewController), and i want to make it more flexible.

**Any suggestion is welcome ~**

## :D

Answer (score -1):

There is already available a specific state machine you could use instead of inventing the wheels: [GKStateMachine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkstatemachine). It has all the required method to transition from state to state. We also use it for different view controller states. Just take you time to read a bit and find some examples, to have your code nice and clean. You will also be able to combine the implementation with a corresponding enum of states, which will just define the states without a need of having associated values there.